# Create a custom map with markers

Tags: android, react-native

I want to create a fully custom map with my own markers and totally responsivly with react native. So I choosed an Image for my map and I just place some markers directly on the map depending of the size of the screen to really have the good location. I tried without screen size and it's a little better but still not perfect..

This is my scrollview code :

```
      <View style={styles.container}>


    <View style={{borderWidth: 1, width : screendim.width / 1.1, height: screendim.height / 2}}>
      <ScrollView>
        <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
          <View>
          <Image  source={require("../resources/map.png")}/>
          </View>
            <Marker top={10} left={300}/>
            <Marker top={500} left={500}/>
            <Marker top={5} left={2}/>
            <Marker top={1.7} left={1.5}/>

        </ScrollView>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>

  </View>
```

And this is my marker code

```
        return(<TouchableOpacity style={{position: "absolute", top :  this.props.top, left : this.props.left, width : imgSize, height: imgSize}} >
        <Image style={{width : imgSize, height: imgSize}} source={require("../../resources/marker.png")}/>
    </TouchableOpacity>)
```

[image: There is the difference between the two screen sizes. Look the right marker, depending on the road, it's not at the same place..]

Comment: is it okey to assume the problem you have is when making it responsive ? not clear about your question.

Comment: Yes exactly, when the screen size changes, the markers positions change too and I don't want that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found a solution, the solution is to not adapt to screen size, so the map is original size and markers too.